# How to make a partially transparent checkerboard in CSS?

Tags: css

I'm using the css gradient checkerboard right now, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how it actually works and how to modify it to be mostly transparent (say 60%).

```css
.checkered {
  background-image: 
   linear-gradient(45deg, #808080 25%, transparent 25%), 
   linear-gradient(-45deg, #808080 25%, transparent 25%), 
   linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #808080 75%), 
   linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #808080 75%);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 10px, 10px -10px, -10px 0px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkered"></div>
```

How could I modify this snippet to control the transparency of the resulting checkerboard?

Comment: You could use `rgba( #808080, 0.6 )` instead of just `#808080`.

Comment: simply apply opacity:0.6 to your element

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways (the first of which is more accepted):

1. Use `rgba()` instead of hex.

RGBA stands for Red, Green, Blue, Alpha (where the "Alpha" is the transparency).

```
.checkered {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0,0,0,.6) 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0,0,0,.6) 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.6) 75%), linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.6) 70%);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 10px, 10px -10px, -10px 0px;
}
```

--- or ---

2. Add the alpha value at the end of your hex: `#808080AA` (0-F just like in hex colors. 0 = completely transparent, F = completely opaque)

[  Warning: Doesn't work in IE as far as I know, and maybe some other browsers ]